 In the Loop 
Follow the ouroboros down valleys and over mountains. Is it even going anywhere?
EDIT (7 days after initial posting): The grid and Penpa+ link have been updated to an easier version, with more numbers filled into the grid. The solution remains unchanged.
Interactive Penpa+ version


Did the ouroboros...

 ...join a CULT?

First, we solve the slitherlink:

 

Next, the lines are reminiscent of

 an origami fold diagram. Specifically, the dashed lines are called "valley" folds, and the dot-dash lines are called "mountain" folds.

The "ouroboros" seems to refer to

 the slitherlink loop itself, so the edges are what's important - ignore the cell coloring (this tripped me up for a while).

So to get the final solution, we can

 print the solved slitherlink and fold along the lines:






This is very very close! Everything looks right, except the final product, which just almost looks right. I'm not sure what's causing the slight shift, but double-check your folding and maybe verify that your overall paper is actually square.

@DanDan面 Should the second-from-bottom-left line be dashed instead of dot-dashed?  I do get something that I could interpret as an answer if I change that fold.

I'll double check this later today.

Yes, the second-from-bottom-left line should be dashed. Sorry about the mistake. I'll edit the post to reflect the change.

Also, congratulations on figuring out that this puzzle involves paper-folding! I've added it to the tags on the puzzle now, but wanted to leave this note here to indicate that you figured it out yourself.

@DanDan面 See my latest edit
